# Understanding Apache Spark Web UI performance metrics

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-webui

I'm new to Spark and I'm trying to understand the metrics in the Web UI that are related to in my Spark Application (developed through Dataset API). I've watched few videos by Spark Summit and Databricks and most of the videos I watched were about a general overview of the Web UI like: definition of stage/job/task, how to understand when something is not working properly (e.g. not balanced work between executors), suggestions about things to avoid while programming, etc.

However, I couldn't find a detailed explaination of each performance metrics. In particular I'm interested understanding the things in the following images that are related to a Query that contains a groupBy(Col1, Col2), a orderBy(Col1, Col2) and a show().

[Job 0](http://prntscr.com/romv71)

If I understood well, the default max partition size is set to 128 MB. Since my dataset size is 1378MB I get 11 tasks that work with 128MB, right? and <s>since in the first stage I did some filtering (before applying groupBy) tasks write in memory so Shuffle Write is 108.3KB but why do I get 200 tasks for second stage?</s>

<s>After the groupBy I used an orderBy, is the number of tasks related to how my dataset is or it is related to the size of it?</s>

**UPDATE**: I found this [spark.sql.shuffle.partitions of 200 default partitions conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950062/spark-sql-shuffle-partitions-of-200-default-partitions-conundrum) and some other questions, but now I'm wondering if there is a specific reason for it to be 200?

[Stage 0](http://prntscr.com/ron05b)

Why some tasks have result serialization here? If I understood well the serialization is related to the output so any show(), count(), collect(), etc. But in this stage those actions are not present (before the groupBy).

[Stage 1](http://prntscr.com/ron36e)

Is it normal that there is a huge part for result serialization time? I called show() (that takes 20 rows by default and there is an orderBy) so all tasks run in parallel and that one serialized all its records?

Why only one task have a considerable Shuffle Read Time? I expected all to have at least a small amount of Shuffle Read Time, again it is something related to my dataset?

The deserialization time is related to reading my dataset file? I'm asking because I wouldnt have expected it there since it is stage 1 and it was already present in stage 0.

[Job 1- caching](http://prntscr.com/ron8fk)

Since I'm dealing with 3 queries that starts from the same dataset, I used cache() at the beginning of the first Query. I was wondering why it shows 739.9MB / 765 [input size/records]  ... In the first query it shows 1378.8 MB / 7647431 [input size/records].

I guess that it has 11 tasks since the size of the dataset cached is still 1378MB but 765 is a really low number compared to the initial that was 7647431 so I dont think it is really related to records/rows, right?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Just a quick question, what part of the interface are these graphs available in? My event timeline only shows me when the executors started, not the portion of time on shuffle writes and such.

Comment: it is on stages, when you click on a stage and open event timeline it shows the tasks