# Spark SQL Window functions - manual repartitioning necessary?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I am processing data partitioned by column "A" with PySpark.

Now, I need to use a window function over another column "B" to get the max value for this frame and count it up for new entries.

As it says [here](https://databricks.com/de/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html), *"Also, the user might want to make sure all rows having the same value for  the category column are collected to the same machine before ordering and calculating the frame."*

Do I need to manually repartition the data by column "B" before applying the window, or does Spark does this automatically?

I.e. would I have to do:

```
data = data.repartition("B")
```

before:

```
w = Window().partitionBy("B").orderBy(col("id").desc())
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Window.partitionBy(someCol)`, then if you have not set a value for shuffle partitions parameter, then the partitioning will default to 200.

A similar but not the same post should provide guidance. [spark.sql.shuffle.partitions of 200 default partitions conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950062/spark-sql-shuffle-partitions-of-200-default-partitions-conundrum)

So, in short you need not expressly perform the repartition, the shuffle partitions parameter is more relevant.