# How to create partitions for two dataframes while couple of partitions can be located on the same instance/machine on Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, bigdata, aws-glue

We have two DataFrames: **df_A**, **df_B**

Let's say, both has a huge # of rows. And we need to partition them.
How to partition them as couples?

For example, partition number is 5:

- df_A partitions: partA_1, partA_2, partA_3, partA_4, partA_5
- df_B partitions: partB_1, partB_2, partB_3, partB_4, partB_5

If we have 5 machines:

- machine_1: partA_1 and partB_1
- machine_2: partA_2 and partB_2
- machine_3: partA_3 and partB_3
- machine_4: partA_4 and partB_4
- machine_5: partA_5 and partB_5

If we have 3 machine:

- machine_1: partA_1 and partB_1
- machine_2: partA_2 and partB_2
- machine_3: partA_3 and partB_3
- ...(when machines are free up)...
- machine_1: partA_4 and partB_4
- machine_2: partA_5 and partB_5

> Note: If one of DataFrames is small enough, we can use **broadcast technique**.

What to do(how to partition) when both (or more than two) DataFrames are large enough?

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to take a step back here. Looking at big sizes aspect only, not broadcast.

Spark is a framework that manages things for your App in terms of co-location of dataframe partitions, taking into account resources allocated vs. resources available and the type of Action, and thus if Workers need to acquire partitions for processing.

`repartition`s are `Transformations`. When an `Action`, such as `write`:

```
peopleDF.select("name", "age").write.format("parquet").save("namesAndAges.parquet")
```

occurs then things kick in.

- If you have a JOIN, then Spark will work out if re-partitioning and movement is required.
- That is to say, if you `join` on c1 for both DF's, then re-partitioning may most likely well occur for the c1 column, so that occurrences in the DF's for that c1 column are shuffled to the same Nodes where a free Executor resides waiting to serve that JOIN of 2 or more partitions.
- That only occurs when an Action is invoked. In this way, if you do unnecessary Transformation, Catalyst can obviate those things.
- Also, for number of partitions used, this is a good link imho: [spark.sql.shuffle.partitions of 200 default partitions conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950062/spark-sql-shuffle-partitions-of-200-default-partitions-conundrum)